# Solving overflow for quadratic roots

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

> Suppose a machine with a floating point system ($\beta$,$t$,$L$,$U$) $ = (10, 8, -50, 50)$ is used to calculate the roots of the quadratic equation
>   $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
>   where $a,b,$ and $c$ are given, real coefficients
>
> For each of the following, state the numerical difficulties that arise if one uses the standard formula for computing the roots. Explain how to overcome these difficulties (if possible)

I am stuck on the third problem that has $a = 10^{-30}, b = -10^{30}, c = 10^{30}$

Solving for the roots we get 
$x = \frac{10^{30} \pm \sqrt{(-10^{30})^2-4(10^{-30}10^{30})}}{2*10^{-30}}$

I have rearranged this equation several times, but I cannot seem to find a way where I do not get something around $10^{60}$, which cannot be represented by this floating point system (I can get rid of squaring $b$ by factoring, but it seems I still end up with $10^{60}$ in the end). I am not sure if it is impossible or if I am missing some sort of trick. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions do not say "solve".  They say "identify the numerical difficulties".  The fact that you get overflow *is* the difficulty.

And there is no way around it if you want both roots.  Clearly one of the roots is close to $1$ and the product of both roots has to be $10^{60}$, so the remaining root is forced to to be too big for your overflow limit (limit = $10^{50}$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = 10^{15} y :$
$$10^{-30} y^2 - 10^{15} y + 1 = 0$$

However, one of x roots will overflow.
Perhaps other calculations can use y instead ?

We sometimes do this, say with logarithm, to extend float range.